# PySpark. Merge schemas by casting to string when reading parquet?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I read data from parquet files, which has a Map type field as below:

```
>>> df = spark.read.parquet('path/to/partiton')
>>> df.collect()
Row(field={'a': 'SomeString', 'b': '1234'})

>>> df.printSchema()
field: map (containsNull = true)
 |-- key: string
 |-- value: string(valueContainsNull = true)
```

The problems is that in other partitions key `a` is `None`, causing key `b` to be read as `long` type:

```
>>> df = spark.read.parquet('path/to/otherPartiton')
>>> df.collect()
Row(field={'a': None, 'b': 1234})

>>> df.printSchema()
field: map (containsNull = true)
 |-- key: string
 |-- value: long(valueContainsNull = true)
```

This produces a clash schema when reading all partitions at the same time:

```
>>> df = spark.read.parquet('path/to/')
>>> df.collect()
SparkException: ... java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: org.apache.parquet.column.values.dictionary.PlainValuesDictionary$PlainLongDictionary
```

I have try to specify the schema manually as below:

```
>>> struct = StructType([ StructField('field', MapType(StringType(), StringType())) ])
>>> df = spark.read.schema(struct).parquet('path/to/')
>>> df.collect()
fails with same error
```

Is there any way to fix this? Am I force to rewrite wrong partitions?

Comment: why are you not using datasets?

Comment: @IvanMilasevic datasets are not available in **py**spark

Answer (score 0):

You can enforce your own schema on the dataframe.

## Schema Definition

```
customschema = StructType([
    StructField("col_01", IntegerType()),
    StructField("col_02", StringType()),
    StructField("col_03", DateType())
])
```

In your application code you can this as below

```
df = spark.read.csv(filename, header=True, nullValue='NA', schema=customschema)
df.show()
```

Comment: I've already tried using custom schema. Read the las part of the question. Also I'm using parquet, not csv